# 500 Error while rendering svg image in angular 1.4.6

Tags: angularjs, svg

I am getting 500 error while passing relative path for svg image element using xlink:href attribute through a java script function.
Angular version : 1.4.6

```
SVG ::
<image ng-if="scores.length > 0" xlink:href="{{getImage(scores[0])}}" ng-attr-transform="translate(100, 100)" ng-attr-height="50" ng-attr-width="50" />

Controller::
$scope.scores = [];
$scope.getImage = function(score) {
 if (score  < 0) {
 return "/images/red.svg";
 }
 if (score > 0) {
 return "/images/green.svg";
 }
 return "/images/gray.svg";
 }
```

Expecting not see the error messages on console